# Linear convolution in the DFT domain

Tags: dft, convolution

Let's say I have 2 sequences a and b in the time domain. Both are length N. A and B are the DFT of a and b. If I do a circular convolution of A and B in freq domain (A o B), then the IDFT of the result will be a x b in the time domain. Correct?
Now what happens if I do linear convolution of A and B in the freq domain, i.e. A*B? The results will have a length of 2N-1. What does the IDFT of the result mean in the time domain?

Notation:

-x is multiplication

-* is linear convolution

-o is circular convolution

Comment: Pad both sequences with N zeroes, and you are with a circular convolution again. See details in https://spinlab.wpi.edu/courses/ece503_2014/12-1linear_convolution_with_DFT.pdf

Comment: Read  up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method